# Sequence of measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Exercise in Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis: my solution and question at the end.

Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers and suppose there are positive integers $N_k$ such that $k\to \infty\Rightarrow N_k\to \infty $ and such that the trigonometric polynomials $P_k(t) =\sum_{-N_k}^{N_k}\left ( 1-\frac{|j|}{N_k+1} \right )c_je^{ijt}$ are $\textit {nonnegative}$ for all $t\in \mathbb R.$ Then there is a positive measure $\mu$ such that $c_n=\int _{\mathbb T}e^{-int}d\mu.$

I can do this if $c_0\neq 0:$

Define the measures $\mu'_k(A)=\int_AP_kdt.$ Then, $\mu_k' (\mathbb T)=2\pi c_0$ and if we take $\mu =\frac{1}{2\pi c_o}\mu',$ then we obtain a sequence of measures $(\mu_k)\subset B_{\mathscr M (\mathbb T)}(0,1).$

As $\mathscr M(\mathbb T)=\mathscr C(\mathbb T)^*, $ and noting that $\mathscr C(\mathbb T)$ is separable, we can say that the unit ball of $\mathscr M(\mathbb T)$ is compact and metrizable in the weak* topology. This means that there is a weakly converging subsequence $(\mu_{k_n})$ of $(\mu_k).$

Now fix $n\in \mathbb N$ and take $f(t)=e^{-int}.\ $ Then, we have

$\tag1 \text {eval}_f(\mu_{k_n})\to \text {eval}_f(\mu)=\int_{\mathbb T}e^{-int}d\mu$.

On the other hand,

$\tag 2\text {eval}_f(\mu_{k_n})=\int_{\mathbb T}fd\mu_{k_n}=\int_{\mathbb T}f\cdot P_{k_n}dt=\int_{\mathbb T}P_{k_n}(t)e^{-int}dt=0\  \text {if} \\ n>N_k \ \text {and} \left ( 1-\frac{n}{N_k+1} \right )c_n \ \text {otherwise}.$

Taking the limit as $k\to \infty$  and combining $(1)$ and $(2),$ we get

$\tag3 c_n=\int_{\mathbb T}e^{-int}d\mu$

and we are done.

I wonder though if there is an easier way to do this. What happens if $c_0=0?$ And what can be said if the $P_k$ are allowed to be complex, so that the measures are now signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the way you did it is the natural approach.

Note that if $c_0=0$ you would have$\int_{\mathbb T}1\,d\mu=0$, so $\mu$ would not be positive. If you remove the restriction of $\mu>0$, you can just work as you did; the problem is that to use the weak$^*$-compactness you need the $\mu_k$ to be uniformly bounded: that would put another restriction no the allowable sequence $(c_n)$.

In the original question the positivity of $P_k$ gave you the boundedness of $\mu_k$, i.e. $\mu_k(\mathbb T)=2\pi c_0$; if you remove the positivity of $P_k$, you would need a uniform bound (on $k$) to have all measures $\mu_k$ inside a ball.